# Showing Post Counts of One's (Author) Own in the admin post list

Tags: admin, query-posts, author

How can I show user's post counts of one's (Author) own in the admin post list (edit.php) instead of all post count of the system? like published (10), Draft (5) ... of his own or logedin user.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here for the solution (code needs optimizing, but it works):
[Help to condense/optimize some working code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34765/help-to-condense-optimize-some-working-code)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be applied automatically if user doesn't have `edit_others_posts` capability for post type ( [source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/edit.php#L143) ).

Otherwise I see no easy way to change it. As many things in admin it is mostly hardcoded and doesn't pass through any filters.

Comment: thanks for your reply Rarst. But I dont let the author to give edit_others_posts capability and they should not also. I need a solution without modifying the core. Thanks.

Comment: @mha if I read code right then if they **don't** have the capability then counts should be limited to **their** posts automatically.